# c++ shared library in custom directory is not found

Tags: c++

I want to use a shared library (resides in a custom directory) into an executable.

I've created this **makefile**

```
all: SayHello

SayHello: compiledObjects/SayHello.o myLib/libNames.so
    g++ compiledObjects/SayHello.o -o SayHello -Icommons -LmyLib -lNames


compiledObjects/SayHello.o: SayHello.cpp
    g++ -c SayHello.cpp -o compiledObjects/SayHello.o

myLib/libNames.so: commons/Names.cpp commons/Names.h
    g++ -shared -fPIC commons/Names.cpp -o myLib/libNames.so
```

That create correctly the executable and shared library infact I can Execute the program using this command

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/custom/path/to/lib/myLib/libNames.so
./SayHello
```

How can I execute `./SayHello` without specify LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

I'm not using any IDE and I'm on linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-rpath` option to link your executable. See the `ld(1)` manual page for more information.

P.S. Your makefile appears to have a bug. If you successfully `make` your program, and immediately run `make` again, looks like your makefile will attempt to recompile the program again, even though nothing has changed.

After all, the whole purpose of a makefile is to avoid doing unneeded compilations.

The `SayHello.o` build target should be `compiledObjects/SayHello.o`.

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed the makefile now (I've updated the new version in the question). For -rpath option I've some trouble... Can you give me the link of DOC please? I'm not able to find.

Comment: Probably i'm wrong but this command `g++ compiledObjects/SayHello.o -o SayHello -Icommons -LmyLib -lNames -rpath` return this error: `g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-rpath’`

Comment: Use "man ld" to read ld's man page. Use "man gcc" to read gcc's man page, namely how to instruct gcc to pass options to the linker. Learning how to find and read technical documentation is a necessary skill that every software developer must have.

Comment: Thanks to you today i've found a mine of gold!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell g++ to pass the `-rpath` option to the linker using `-Wl,-rpath`. Also, you need to specify a path to the `-rpath` option.

Putting it all together your last build step should look like this:

```
SayHello: compiledObjects/SayHello.o myLib/libNames.so
    g++ compiledObjects/SayHello.o -o SayHello -Icommons -LmyLib -lNames -Wl,-rpath=/custom/path/to/lib/myLib/
```

**Relative RPATH:**
If you want to specify an RPATH relative to your binary you should use 
`$ORIGIN` as a placeholder: `-rpath='$ORIGIN/rel/path'`.